# Ideal feature map size for a tic-tac-toe game CNN?

Tags: conv-neural-network

I've read many other posts with similar questions but most answers seem to be around it being an "art", which is probably ok for arbitrary images because we don't know exactly which and how many features are going to be learned. But if we already know the features that we want the CNN to learn, can we make educated guesses?

For example, in the game of tic-tac-toe (noughts and crosses), we know that we're looking for straight lines 2 pixels deep and placements where our move ends up taking the center or corner positions (lets ignore any other features for now). So, we can probably count the ideal feature map size as follows -

2 (2 slanted lines) + 1 (1 vertical line) + 1 (1 horizontal line) + 1 (center placement) + 4 (corner placement) = 9 feature maps?

Is my above understanding of feature maps correct?

Note: I'm using tic-tac-toe (noughts and crosses) just as a very simple example for learning CNN programming. My understanding of feature maps (please feel free to correct if wrong) is that they correspond to actual features like lines, curves etc (at least in the first layer).